# How can i paint over text instead of printing multiple times?

Tags: python, windows

How can I make the program print the CTRL+C to go BACK once down?[Look pictures][Picture][1]

````
            while h < math.inf:
                time2 = time.strftime("[%H" + ":%M" + ":%S]")
                console = colorama.Fore.WHITE + time2 + '' + defaultname
                file = open("Accounts/Failed.txt", "a+")
                file2 = open("Accounts/Success.txt", "a+")
                x = random.randrange(0, 100)
                f = generator()
                if x <= 97:
                    print(console + colorama.Fore.RED + "[FAILED]  " + "0x" + f + ' ETH Wallet' + colorama.Fore.WHITE + '       CTRL+C to go BACK')
                    file.write(str(j) + ":0x" + f + "\n")
                    time.sleep(0.15)
                    j += 1
                    file.close()
                elif x >= 97:
                    print(console + colorama.Fore.GREEN + "[SUCCESS] " + "0x" + f + ' ETH Wallet' + colorama.Fore.WHITE + '       CTRL+C to go BACK')
                    file2.write(str(h) + ":0x" + f + "\n")
                    time.sleep(0.15)
                    h += 1
                    file2.close()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa7Bw.png
````

Comment: Can you precise what's working and what's not in your code, and show us a minimum reproductible example ?

Comment: The code is working just fine, I just want to achieve this and I don't know how https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa7Bw.png basically make a loop print the random strings but print the "CTRL+C" once on the bottom of the screen (like in the photo)

Answer (score 0):

So to print `CTRL+C to go BACK` only on the last loop iteration, you have too check if `h + 1` is going to break the loop condition. To do so, you could check the condition `h + 1 >= math.inf`.

```
if h + 1 >= math.inf:
    print("CTRL+C to go BACK")
```

This way you'll have to remove the `CTRL+C to go BACK` in your infos print functions